# Simplifying powershell cmdlet

Tags: exchange, command-line-interface, powershell

I have a powershell cmdlet (move-IMAPMailboxToExchange) that requires a lot of repetition to enter.  I want to call it with another batch/powershell script that just takes two args from the command line.  I've tried every calling convention I can think of but I can't make it work.

I want this:

```
Move-IMAPMailboxToExchange -SourcePassword P@ssW0rd! -allowunsecureconnection -sourceLoginId username -sourceserver source.ser.ver -sourceidentity username@mail.dom.ain targetclientaccessserver "client.access.ser.ver" -targetidentity username@mail.dom.ain -verbose
```

To be this:

```
migrate-user username P@ssW0rd!
```

I've tried $args, but that seems to expand.  I've tried $args[0] which works in the bareword password and sourcelogin, but doesn't work next to the @mail....  I've tried %1, etc, from the old DOS days but that doesn't work.

I'm a unix dork and I'm not quite grokking powershell yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, single-quotes is how PowerShell designates something as 'do not parse'. so...

You might want to do something like this

```
$username=$args[0]
$passwd=$args[1]

Move-IMAPMailboxToExchange [all that jazz]
```

As a way to firmly declare the variables within the context of the script. If you're having trouble constructing the -sourceidentity and -targetidentity variables, you may want to pre-construct them before putting them on the move-imaptoexchange command...

```
$sourceident="$username"+'@srcmail.dom.ain'
$targeditent="$username"+'@tgtmail.dom.ain'
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks!  It correctly interpolated the variable next to the @ sign so I didn't need to make temp variables for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a function or script file around your cmdlet, like this:

```
    function migrate-user
{
 param($username,$password)

Move-IMAPMailboxToExchange -SourcePassword $password -allowunsecureconnection -sourceLoginId $username -sourceserver 'source.ser.ver' -sourceidentity "$username`@mail.dom.ain" targetclientaccessserver 'client.access.ser.ver' -targetidentity "$username`@mail.dom.ain" -verbose

}
```